# Move files in folders by list in file

Tags: shell, move

I have a `.txt` file that has a list of folders:

```
old_folder_path1,new_folder_path1
old_folder_path2,new_folder_path2
old_folder_path3,new_folder_path3
```

I would like to run a shell command that moves the files from within the old folder to the new folder for each series of folders. Also does not overwrite and does not move subfolders, just the files in each folder.

I can change the syntax of the `.txt` file as necessary to accommodate this.

Comment: note that comma is a valid character in a filename, so anything using this could break if either or both of old and new directory names contain a comma.   Actually, it's easy enough to deal with the new dir having a comma (just limit the field split to the first comma only), but not if the old dir has one...and not if you can't tell which one is supposed to have an embedded comma. Probably safest just to report an error if there are > 1 commas in the input and continue to the next line.

Answer (score 0):

Using `rsync`:

```
while IFS=, read -r src dest; do
    [ ! -d "$src" ] && echo "skipping missing directory \"$src\"" >&2 && continue
    mkdir -p "$dest" && rsync -av --exclude='*/' --remove-source-files --ignore-existing "$src/" "$dest"
done < file.txt
```

This script reads `file.txt` line by line and assigns source and target directory to variables `src` and `dest`. The line is split on the comma defined in the `IFS` (internal field separator) variable.
If `src` is not a directory, the while-loop continues with the next line, otherwise the destination directory and its parent directories are created if it doesn't exist.

In the `rsync` call the following options are used (see `man rsync`):

- `-a` archive mode (shorthand for options `-rlptgoD`)
- `-v` verbose mode
- `--exclude='*/'` exclude directories, only non-directories are transferred
- `--remove-source-files` remove files from the sending side when transfer is complete (like `mv`)
- `--ignore-existing` don't transfer files that already exist on the destination side

You could save the script as a shell script `mv_rsync.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

[ $# -ne 1 ] && echo "invalid file argument" >&2 && exit 1
while IFS=, read -r src dest; do
    [ ! -d "$src" ] && echo "skipping missing directory \"$src\"" >&2 && continue
    mkdir -p "$dest" && rsync -av --exclude='*/' --remove-source-files --ignore-existing "$src/" "$dest"
done < "$1"
```

Make it executable with

```
chmod +x ./mv_rsync.sh
```

and run it as

```
./mv_rsync.sh file.txt
```

Comment: or instead of rsync, use find. e.g. something like `find "$src/" -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec mv -n -t "$dst/" {} +`

Comment: @freddy Thanks, but I get the following errors:

run.sh: line 2:$'/r':c command not found

Comment: @user374369 It seems you have [edited the file in Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966488/how-do-i-fix-r-command-not-found-errors-running-bash-scripts-in-wsl). Run `dos2unix run.sh` to convert the Windows line endings (CR LF) to Unix (LF) style and try again (and maybe do the same on `file.txt`).